# React chart js not showing any colors

Tags: css, reactjs, react-chartjs

The colors in the chart are not showing, however it still works as it shows tooltips and data correctly.

This is the pie chart card.

```html
<Card title={t('Sensors')} bordered={false}>
   <Row gutter={10}>
      <Col span={14}>
         <Card title={t('Packages')}>
              <Space direction="vertical" size={8}>
                   <Space><MessageFilled style={{ fontSize: 'large', color: "#815AED" }} /><Text className={styles.property}>{data.datasets[0].data[0]}%</Text> {t('Received')}</Space>
                    <Space><MessageFilled style={{ fontSize: 'large', color: "#d4d4d4" }} /><Text className={styles.property}>{data.datasets[0].data[1]}%</Text> {t('Lost')}</Space>
              </Space>
          </Card>
      </Col>
      <Col span={10}>
         <Doughnut redraw={true} data={data}
             options={{
                 plugins: {
                    legend: {
                       display: false
                    }
                 }
             }}
         />
      </Col>

   </Row>
</Card>
```

And this is the grid container style that contains all cards:

```css
.gridcontainer {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 450px);
    grid-row-gap: 12px;
    grid-column-gap: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
}

.gridcontainer>.griditem {
    padding: 6px;
    min-width: 0;
}
```

All of them follow this structure:

```html
<div className={styles.gridcontainer}>
   <div className={styles.griditem}>
      <DashboardCard type={"info"} data={props} />
   </div>
   <div className={styles.griditem}>
     <DashboardCard type={"donut"} data={{
        labels: ['Received', 'Lost'],
        datasets: [{
        label: '% of Messages',
        data: [messages.received, messages.lost],
        backgrounddivor: ["#815AED", "#d4d4d4"],
        borderWidth: 0
        }]
     }} />
   </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOck3.png)

I tried changing it to a static grid and it worked like that, however I need it to be dynamic.